# ScrollBar does not move down with arrow keys while selecing items

Tags: html, css, scroll

I want to move the scrollbar top or bottom while selecting items using keyboard keys.

```
<div
     style="width: 100%; overflow-y:auto; max-height: 270px;;" 
     class="suggestion-items">
  <div
       style="width:100%;"        
       class="suggestion-item">
    {{items}}
  </div>
</div>
```

SOME CSS ARE AS FOLLOWS

```
.suggestion-items {
    border: 1px solid;
    border-color: @typeahead-item-border;
    color: @typeahead-item-color;
    background-color: @typeahead-item-bg;
    position: absolute;
    top: 32px;
    z-index: @zindex-typeahead; 
    width: 100%;
}
```

Here I am able to select the result items using keyboard, but the scrollbar does not move while selecting the items which are hidden inside the container. Since I have given overflow-y:auto; with max-height:270px; so that scrollbar appear.

Comment: can you provide a plunkr/stackblitz example?

Comment: I want something like this http://jsfiddle.net/4jtg8y3b/ in above code

Comment: I meant of your not working example... that helps the other contributors to reproduce the problem you have :)

Comment: See the scenario is this you type something in searchbar and searchbar suggest you some keywords. Since there are 100s of keywords I only show 10 to 15 at a time. Now when the user try to explore other keywords he move the keyboard down key. The problem here is that while selecting th keyword(item) the scrollbar does not move from top bottom.